# $U_1=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1+x_2>1\}$ open, closed, compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> $U_1=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x+y>1\}$ open, closed, compact?

Closed?:

No, $U_1$ is not closed since $(0.5+1/n,0.5+1/n)_{n} \in U_1$, but as $n\to \infty$, we have $(1,1)\notin U_1$, thus $U_1$ is not closed and hence not compact.

Open?:

I wanted to show that $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash U_1=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x+y\leq 1\}$ is closed. Let $(a_n)_n\subset \mathbb{R}^2\backslash U_1$ with $a_n=(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y)$. I have to show that $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus U_1$. I wanted to use the maximum metric:$$\left | \left |\begin{pmatrix} x_n\\y_n \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix} \right | \right |_\infty = \max \{x-x_n,y-y_n\}$$ How can i continue?

Comment: Take any point in $ U_1$ and put an open ball around it that is entirely in $ U_1$. Then $U_1$ is a union of open balls, hence open. It might help to note that there is a unique minimizer of $||u-x||$ with $u \in U_1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash U_1$, and you can take the distance and divide by two to get the radius for your ball.

Comment: Why not just show directly that $U_1$ is open? It’s the set of points above the line $x+y=1$, so for any point $p\in U_1$ the open ball $B(p,r)$ is contained in $U_1$ provided that $r$ is at most the distance from $p$ to that line.

Comment: Let $(x,y)\in U_1$. Then $x+y = z > 1$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{z-1}{2}$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is open because the function $f(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous. Then, the  preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ of any open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, $x_n+y_n\leqslant1$. Suppose that $x+y>1$. There is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\max\{|x-x_n|,|y-y_n|\}<\frac12(x+y-1);$$in other words,$$-\frac12(x+y-1)<|x-x_n|,|y-y_n|<\frac12(x+y-1).$$So, if $n\geqslant N$,\begin{align}x_n+y_n-1&=x+y-1+(x_n-x)+(y_n-y)\\&>x+y-1-\frac12(x+y-1)-\frac12(x+y-1)\\&=0.\end{align}But we were assuming that $x_n+y_n\leqslant1$.